Finiteness of Selmer group
I was reading the proof of finiteness of $S^n(E/\mathbb{Q})$ but I am unable to understand from the following lemma how it follows that $S^n(E/L)$ finite.

LEMMA 3.13 For any finte subset $T$ of $\mathcal{P}$ containing $\mathcal{P}(\infty)$, let $N$ be the kernel of
$$
a\mapsto \left(ord_{\mathfrak{p}}(a) \mod n \right)\colon L^\times/L^{\times n} \to \bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}\notin T}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Then there is an exact sequence
$$
0\to U_T/U^n_T\to N \to (C_T)_n
$$

Reference is Milne's Elliptic curve book:


It's best to include the text of what you are referring to, not just a picture, not least because a picture is not accessible to everyone. My guess is that the downvotes were because of this. I've edited at least the statement of the lemma in, because I guess that's all you meant to refer to.

This is explained in detail in IV, 3.14, and following text in the second edition of the book you cite (probably better than the first edition).

@DavidRoberts thank you. I will keep this in mind.

Here's the explanation in the second edition of the work you cite.


Better to type this out etc, as I commented on the question. Or at the least write a short summary of the argument....

@anon Thank you so much. But I am not able to get the pdf version of the second edition. I have searched in Library Genesis too.

@anon can you please tell me what is lemma 3.8 and 3.6 in the above attach photo ? Thank you in advance.
